# line 2 error python crash course eric matthes problem 9-2

Tags: python, class

This is in chapter 9. The three restaurants problem, says there's a syntax error with the colon in line 2. Don't understand why that would be or if the error is somewhere else. May have mistyped something somewhere but not sure where, probably something simple i overlooked. Thanks.

Here's the code:

class Restaurant():

```
def__init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
    self.name = name.title()
    self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
    
def describe_restaurant(self):
    msg = self.name + " serves wonderful " + self.cuisine_type + "."
    print("\n" + msg)
    
def open_restaurant(self):
    msg = self.name + " is open. Come on in!"
    print("\n" + msg)
    
mean_queen = Restaurant('the mean queen', 'pizza')
mean_queen.describe_restaurant()

ludvigs = Restaurant("ludvig's bistro", 'seafood')
ludvigs.describe_restaurant()

mango_thai = Restaurant('mango thai', 'thai food')
mango_thai.describe_restaurant()
```

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: Never mind.  The problem is that you forgot the space after `def` in `def__init__`.

Comment: sorry bout that, here you go, runfile('C:/Users/josep/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/josep/.spyder-py3')
  File "C:\Users\josep\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 2
    def__init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: thought thats what it was, i tried changing that and it didnt fix it, maybe ill try again lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues, try this. You may have missed the indentation after your class declaration

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, name, cuisine_type):
        self.name = name.title()
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        msg = self.name + " serves wonderful " + self.cuisine_type + "."
        print("\n" + msg)
        
    def open_restaurant(self):
        msg = self.name + " is open. Come on in!"
        print("\n" + msg)
    
mean_queen = Restaurant('the mean queen', 'pizza')
mean_queen.describe_restaurant()

ludvigs = Restaurant("ludvig's bistro", 'seafood')
ludvigs.describe_restaurant()

mango_thai = Restaurant('mango thai', 'thai food')
mango_thai.describe_restaurant()
```

output

```
The Mean Queen serves wonderful pizza.

Ludvig'S Bistro serves wonderful seafood.

Mango Thai serves wonderful thai food.
>
```